# Threads Execution

Tags: java, android

I have two threads t1 and t2. each having the code

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

The problem is that the line doesn't works for Thread t2 and the main thread.

Here is the code:

```
package arj.developer.jaadu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp1,mp2;
    View v;
    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);          
            mp1=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.jaad);
            mp1.start();
        }
    };
    Thread t2= new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            mp2=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.jaad);
            mp1.stop();
            mp2.start();
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        try {
            t1.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t1.start();
        try {
            t2.sleep(30000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what is the goal after all?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev  i want the screen background to change after every few seconds with music in background

Comment: Why do you need two threads for that? If you switch the background 20 times are you going to have 20 threads?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev I am a newbie..a solutions to this is requested Sir!!

Comment: I suggest you use single `Handler` for that. See the tutorial here: http://binarybuffer.com/2012/07/executing-scheduled-periodic-tasks-in-android

Answer (score 0):

[sleep()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long,%20int%29) causes the CURRENT thread to sleep, so your `t1.sleep(10000)` and `t2.sleep(10000)` both caused the main thread to sleep!
Move the sleep method to t1 & t2's `run()` method, and you probably should run `getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(_color_);` in main thread as well.

```
package arj.developer.jaadu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp1,mp2;
    View v;
    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);   
            }
        });       
            mp1=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.jaad);
            mp1.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            }
        });   
            mp2=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.jaad);
            mp1.stop();
            mp2.start();
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: why would t1.sleep() or t2.sleep() cause for sleep of main thread??

Comment: Because sleep() is a **static** method and causes the currently running thread to sleep, so it doesn't matter at all which Thread instance you are calling it from. See the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long,%20int%29

Comment: if I write t1.start(); and t2.start(); in onCreate();
then the thread t2 is executed only;
I want that there is some delay between execution of Main,t1 and t2

Comment: Yes, so modify the program as I have recommended.

Comment: I tried modifying it...but some times thread t1 gets executed only, sometimes only t2 and Main thread..i want all to execute with some delay....Plzz help with code snippet!!